# How can I sort 4 related lists based on the values in one of the lists?

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have 4 lists that are names, scores in each round, and total scores.

```
names  = ["jack","mike","steve","jessica","jennifer"]
round1 = [20,25,15,10,30]
round2 = [10,20,10,25,20]
total  = [30,45,25,35,50]
```

I want to write in descending order according to the total score.And then i print with using for loops like a table.So the related elements must be in the same indexes. But I couldn't do the rounds according to the total score with the sorted and zip functions. Is there a way to do this?

I tried to write like this

```
total, names = zip(*sorted(zip(total, names)))
total, round1 = zip(*sorted(zip(total, round1)))
total, round2 = zip(*sorted(zip(total, round2)))
```

And then I reverse the lists
When I do this, the order of total and names is correct, but the rounds are wrong.

The output I want is like this(according to total):

```
 names   round1 round2 total
 jennifer  30------20-----50
 mike     25------20-----45
 jessica    10------25-----35
 jack     20------10-----30
 steve   15------10-----25
```

Comment: If you find an answer to your question, please don't forget to click the grey tick beside it to mark it as "accepted".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to `zip` them all, then sort on the `x[3]` value which is the total

```
values = list(zip(names, round1, round2, total))
values.sort(key=lambda x: x[3], reverse=True)
```

Then iterates over the pairs made

```
print(f"{'names':10s}{'round1':7s}{'round2':7s}{'total':6s}")
for n, r1, r2, tot in values:
    print(f"{n:10s}{r1:<7d}{r2:<7d}{tot:<6d}")

names     round1 round2 total
jennifer  30     20         50
mike      25     20         45
jessica   10     25         35
jack      20     10         30
steve     15     10         25
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you overwrite `total` with sorted list, thus further sorting won't do anything. Use:

`_, names = zip(*sorted(zip(total, names)))` to throw away first of the lists.

Though I would suggest better solution:

`total, names, round1, round2 = zip(*sorted(zip(total, names, round1, round2)))`